# Showing $4x + 4b^2 x \leq 4 + (x + b^2 x)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, contest-math, quadratics

I am working on a problem, and I got to a point where I will be done if I can show that for any $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and any constant $b$, 
$$
4x + 4b^2 x \leq 4 + (x + b^2 x)^2.
$$

As a sanity check, I've checked that the equation holds for $x = 0, x = 1,$ and $x = 2$. How can I extend this to other all $x$ between $0$ and $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=b^2x$ then

$$
4x + 4y \leq 4 + (x + y)^2.
$$
and let $t=x+y$
$$
4t \leq 4 + t^2.
$$
which is true since: $0\leq (t-2)^2$.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: Elementary algebra strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

Guide: It holds true for more $x$ than what you expected.

$$4(x+b^2x) \le 4 + (x+b^2x)^2$$

$$(x+b^2x)^2-2(2)(x+b^2x)+2^2 \ge 0$$

Can you use the formula $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$  to simplify the inequality above?

Comment: More specifically, $(a-2)^2 = a^2-4a+4$.